# Как правильно удалить строку в SQL базе?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-sqlite

Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
syntax error

```
DELETE FROM Table_Name WHERE SingerName='Name Singer - ev'ry time')
```

Как видим в названии композиции содержится символ "`'`" (Name Singer - ev'ry time), собственно из за этого возникает проблема удаления строки данной командой. Удаляем с помощью SQLiteDatabase sdb.delete();. Какие пути решения? Есть ли смысл использовать StringReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ можно экранировать

```
DELETE FROM Table_Name WHERE SingerName='Name Singer - ev''ry time'
```

Хотя, не приложу ума зачем вам это. При подстановке параметров происходит автоматическое экранирование

```
sdb.delete("Table_Name", "SingerName = ?", new String[] { "Name Singer - ev'ry time" });
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Просто при `sdb.delete("Table_Name", SINGER_NAME + "='" + getSong() + "'", null); `
Не происходит экранирования..